# How to rresolve the error: /var/cache/apt/archives/wireshark-common_1.11.3+svn54990-0ubuntu1~saucy1~ppa0_amd64.deb

Tags: wireshark

I have an ubuntu 13.10 and try to install wireshark on it. But I keep on getting the following error.

```
mininet@ubun_13_10:~/mininet$ sudo apt-get install wireshark
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  wireshark-common
Suggested packages:
  snmp-mibs-downloader
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wireshark
The following packages will be upgraded:
  wireshark-common
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 75.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 318716 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace wireshark-common 1.10.2-1 (using .../wireshark-common_1.11.3+svn54990-0ubuntu1~saucy1~ppa0_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement wireshark-common ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/wireshark-common_1.11.3+svn54990-0ubuntu1~saucy1~ppa0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/wireshark/init.lua', which is also in package libwireshark-data 1.10.6-1ubuntu2~ppa2~s
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package wireshark.
Unpacking wireshark (from .../wireshark_1.11.3+svn54990-0ubuntu1~saucy1~ppa0_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wireshark-common_1.11.3+svn54990-0ubuntu1~saucy1~ppa0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
mininet@ubun_13_10:~/mininet$ 


mininet@ubun_13_10:/etc/init.d$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10"
mininet@ubun_13_10:/etc/init.d$
```

What should I do to resolve the above error?

Comment: Please upgrade to 14.04, 13.10 ends it life today...

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following commands: (It worked for me with Ubuntu 12.04)

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/wireshark-common_1.11.3+svn54990-
0ubuntu1~saucy1~ppa0_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to explain the commands to improve the answer. (Such as you are downloading from Saucy PPA)